# Remove smaller list with common items in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

`[[1, 2], [2, 4, 6], [6, 9], [9, 10, 11], [11, 20], [20, 25, 30]]`

I want to remove from this the smaller lists that have the same items bigger lists. For example, the result for the above list should be:

`[[2, 4, 6], [9, 10, 11], [20, 25, 30]]`

Since `[1, 2]` and `[2, 4, 6]` has the common item `2`, and

`len([2, 4, 6]) > len([1, 2])`

I can't think of a way to do this without horrible nested for-loops. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest writing the horrible nested for loops as a first pass, then optimize once you have the functionality you want. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: 1 is not anywhere on the final list after the transformation, is that ok?

Comment: @JacobIRR a valuable advice indeed.

Comment: @DYZ yeah it would help if 1 was in the list too, but I could fix that with some minor noodling.

Comment: Then your question is not clear. Why is it ok to remove 1 but not 2 or 6 or 9? What makes it different?

Comment: @DYZ Sorry I meant all the single items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
data = [[1, 2], [2, 4, 6], [6, 9], [9, 10, 11], [11, 20], [20, 25, 30]]

result = []
for e in sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True):
    if not any(set(e).intersection(prev) for prev in result):
        result.append(e)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 4, 6], [9, 10, 11], [20, 25, 30]]
```